A question from STEMS (by CMI) involving geometry, angle chasing, and precalculus algebra.
The QUESTION IS:

Given a quadrilateral ABCD such that $∠ACD = 66^\circ$, $∠ADB = 51^\circ$, $∠BDC = 21^\circ$ and $∠ACB = 48^\circ$
. Suppose AD = a, BC = b, AC = d then find the value of $100\frac{BD}{\sqrt{b(a+d+b)}} + 2$

I thought like this:
As a normal student would do after doing angle chasing I got many angles, which were confusing, but got and angle which was 45 degrees, applied cos rule but got nothing special. Please help if you can

This is from STEMS 2024 Question number 7

Similar to your other STEMS geometry question, let's use wishful thinking to back out how they created the problem / the underlying theory.

Let's force out a length that is equal to $(a+d+b)$.

Considering that we want $b(a+d+b)$, let's consider making the length in that same direction as $BC$.
Notice that $ 180 ^ \circ - 48 ^ \circ - 66^\circ  = 66^\circ$, so to extend $BC = b$ by length $d$, let's reflect $A$ about $CD$ to a point $A'$. Then, $CA' = CA = d$.


Now that we have $b+d$, let's extend it by length $a = DA = DA'$

This time, we construct the external angle bisector of $DA'C$, and reflect $D$ to $D'$.
This gives us $b(a+d+b) = BC \times BD'$.


I guess power of a point is involved. Esp because we want to take square roots, we want to find the tangent from $B$ to some circle continuing $C , D'$.

Furthermore, if $BD$ is tangential to the circumcircle of $DBD'$ at $D$, then $BC \times BD' = BD^2$, which would give us an answer of $\boxed{102}$.
How can we prove this? Well, we know that $\angle BDC = 21^\circ$, so we need to show that $\angle DD'B = 21^\circ$.

Direct angle chasing shows that $\angle BA'D = \angle DAC = 42^\circ$, $\angle A'D'D = \angle A'DD' = \frac{42^\circ}{2}  = 21^\circ$, hence we are done.




Now, write up the solution in the forward direction.

This approach also shows you how the angles were chosen.
We used $\angle ACB +  2 \times ACD= 180^\circ$ and $2 \angle BDC + \angle ADC + \angle ACD = 180^\circ$





I hope you have done all the angle chasing. Let's say that the point where $AC$ and $BD$ meet is $O$. Let's call $\angle CAB=x$ and $\angle ABD=y$
Applying sine rule in $\Delta ADC$ will yield 
$\frac{a}{\sin 66}=\frac{d}{\sin 72}$
Applying sine rule in $\Delta BDC$ will yield 
$\frac{b}{\sin 21}=\frac{BD}{\sin 114}$
Applying sine rule in $\Delta AOD$ will yield 
$\frac{a}{\sin 87}=\frac{AO}{\sin 51}$
Applying sine rule in $\Delta BOC$ will yield 
$\frac{b}{\sin 87}=\frac{BO}{\sin 48}$
Applying sine rule in $\Delta ADB$ will yield 
$\frac{a}{\sin y}=\frac{BD}{\sin (42+x)}$
Applying sine rule in $\Delta AOB$ will yield 
$\frac{AO}{\sin y}=\frac{BO}{\sin x}$
$\implies \displaystyle\frac{\frac{a\sin51}{\sin87}}{\sin y}=\frac{\frac{b\sin48}{\sin87}}{\sin x}$
$\implies \frac{BD}{\sin (42+x)}\sin51=\frac{b}{\sin x}\sin48$
$\implies \frac{\frac{b}{\sin 21}\sin114}{\sin (42+x)}\sin51=\frac{b}{\sin x}\sin48$
$\implies \frac{\sin114\sin51}{\sin21\sin(42+x)}=\frac{\sin48}{\sin x}$
Expand $\sin(42+x)$ and then divide the equation by $\sin x$ on both sides then find the value of $\cot x$ and then find $x$ and after that it follows that $y=87-x$
Now solve the system of equations $\frac{a}{\sin 66}=\frac{d}{\sin 72},\frac{b}{\sin 21}=\frac{BD}{\sin 114},\frac{a}{\sin 87}=\frac{AO}{\sin 51},\frac{b}{\sin 87}=\frac{BO}{\sin 48},AO+CO=d, BO+DO=BD$
where
$CO=\frac{b\sin45}{\sin 87}$
and
$DO=\frac{a\sin42}{\sin 87}$
Find $a,b,d,BD$ and plug them into your expression to get the answer.

at last lines CO = $b\frac{sin45}{sin87}$.

@NamenotAllowed corrected...btw do you have the official solution with you?

STEMS exam is conducted by CMI and it does not provide any kind of answer key or solution, thus I dont have the official solution with me.

@NamenotAllowed ohh...nvm...btw CMI is Chennai Mathematical Institute na?

Yes its by Chennai Mathematical Institute
